# How can my crossover be improved? Efficiency is too low

Tags: circuit-design, passive-networks, speakers, efficiency, passive-filter

I have been working on redoing the crossover for a pair of Dayton audio B652 Speakers, and have just been working on it through a breadboard for practice. I bought a bunch of cheap parts from bojack on amazon for the project. To describe my thought process behind the circuit: I wanted to attenuate the tweeter using an L-pad but it completely sucked all the power out of the circuit. I tried a high resistance value for the parallel R but it wasn't enough. This is why the resistor values are so high in series. For the woofer circuit, I put a resistor in series with the capacitor to modulate the response. I somehow managed to get the FR response to +/- 3db from 200hz to 20khz(measured in-room using REW), and it's flat at the crossover point, but the efficiency is far too low. I am also hearing very audible distortion when I push the volume but I think this is because I am not using audio-grade components. How can I improve the efficiency and distortion of the circuit? I would love to go active but that's a project for another time :).

[image]

Comment: What are the impedance frequency plots for each speaker? Have you tried simulating the circuit? What was wrong with the original crossover filters? Please provide a data sheet link for the inductor and capacitors used.

Comment: I have not run an impedance sweep because I don't have the tools. I have simulated it in Ltspice but isn't very accurate because it's quite difficult to simulate a speaker. I also can't do it in Xsim because I don't have the FR info for the drivers. Couldn't find it anywhere. The original crossover was just a 6.7uF capacitor. The woofer maxes out at 4000hz and then starts breaking up, and that was where the crossover point was. Needed to get the woofer out of the way much sooner to avoid distortion. The crossover point was also dipped, so the two drivers weren't in-phase.

Comment: The inductors are PVC insulated DIP Radial Power Choke type. No other data given but I'm assuming the tolerance is +/- 15-20%. The capacitors are electrolytic and they have a tolerance of +/- 20%. The 22uf cap is rated at 25V and the 47uf is at 10V. The resistors are all 0.5W with a 1% tolerance. Frankly surprised I didn't burn out the components pushing 10+ Watts through it.

Comment: There isn't much you can do about efficiency, then again, the difference *in loudness* between ideal series components and `cheap parts` will be barely audible. Using a tweeter much below its "previous range" risks using it near its resonance, which is "difficult" with a traditional/passive crossover, and drive it into *clipping*: for the same spl, membrane movement needs to greater at lower frequencies.

Comment: So is the efficiency mainly due to the poor driver quality? I am using many more components on the crossover than originally used but the sensitivity isn't even close to other passive bookshelves with more complex crossovers (they are usually 86db, mine is probably 73-76). Your point about the tweeter is fair. I forgot that lowering the crossover point may have taxed the tweeter more than it can handle leading to the distortion I was mentioning. It's a matter of either leaving the woofer as is and having distortion there, or lowering the crossover point and having distortion in the tweeter.